# VSCode Java Extension Pack: sudden linter, refactoring, semantic highlighting issues

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

Don't know how to go about describing the details of my problem, but out of nowhere all of the useful code tools that I use for Java have partially stopped working. `Go To Definition`, `Change All Occurences`, and hover functionalities have all disappeared. I'm working on a remote machine through SSH, but I don't think that's the problem because another computer I'm working on works fine.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling every extension I have, I've tried quitting and restarting VSCode, I've tried deleting and reinstalling the application, all to no avail. I'm desperately in need of help with this problem

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out -- I had to start the RedHat language server extension from a clean slate with the command `Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace`